# Can't update GNOME Extensions on 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

Every time I reboot my PC I get a GNOME Extensions warning that several of my extensions are ready for updating. When I go to the installed updates and click on the update icon I get an error along the lines, "*Can't update the extension because it's in use*". I proceed to disable the extension, then try to update again, and I just get a red `ERROR`. Then I try and uninstall and reinstall and keep getting the same red `ERROR`.

How do I fix this problem (other than installing KDE Plasma, XFCE, etc.)?

Comment: If/when you see the RED error, restart gnome-shell with ALT-F2, r, then ENTER. Then RELOAD the web page. If it's still RED, the extension may not be compatible with 20.04. Note: You can't update the `Desktop Icons` extension.

Comment: another note, this will not work on Wayland - https://askubuntu.com/questions/964068/when-will-wayland-support-restarting-the-shell-by-command