# can wayland (one day) implement restarting (or reloading all internal data of) gnome shell? wayland (or gnomeshell) have what is required for that?

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, reboot, wayland, memory-leak

I read wayland is more secure (how tho?).
But being able to restart gnome-shell is essential as it ends up using 1.5GB ram..
And when I did that with xorg, things worked better just after.

Many ppl recommend re-login, but I dont want to do that as there are many things I have to prepare in a development environment...

So, does wayland have the required code to let gnomeshell be restarted w/o having to re-login? I mean, could someone try to implement it or it is just impossible or so complicated that is totally out of scope?

**Another (and may be much better) way would be to let gnomeshell not be restarted, but instead, ask it nicely to unload all data (images, databases, everything that could bloat and create memory leaks) and then reload (without restarting) all such data.**

Comment: answer to this and probably will stay the same as this q+a:  https://askubuntu.com/a/964075/15811  No not possible and not going to happen. It is not possible and is part of the security measures that got xorg replaced by it

Comment: @Rinzwind that makes sense, but I just thought that gnomeshell could be asked nicely to unload all it's data (images, databases etc, anything that could bloat and create memory leaks) and then reload everything? I just updated the OP